# Problems when trying to start the redis with dump.rdb file

Tags: linux, redis, dump

I'm trying to start redis with a dump.rdb file on linux, but I get a core error. However, when I start on Windows with te same file, it runs perfectly. Also, if I try to start on this Linux machine with a smaller file, it seems that it starts.
Could it be a memory problem?
Thanks!
Amparo

Comment: What is the error code? What are the Redis versions involved here?

Comment: @ItamarHaber I'm not sure that there is interoperability with rdb files between Win and "real" redis. Also this could be simply the recent bug found when loading 2.8 rdbs into 4.0

Comment: If you suspect memory, have you tried it on a linux machine with more memory?  You can rent Linux servers with more (or different sized) memory by the hour at Amazon, Google, and many other places,  to try it out and then delete it when you are done.

Comment: The Redis version is 2.4.14 and I don't know which is the error. A big file core is generated (129 Mb) with characteres like w  îÝ²      p... and some words and sentences like: "pthread_init(): Error from checkpnt_unblock     pthread_create(): thread_setcredentials error..." or "USER DEFINED MALLOC ERROR:
    Unable to load user supplied object: "%s", load() errno == %d..."

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer IDK what to think, but basic triage in this case requires at least that (blaaah windows) ;)

Answer (score 0):

i had the similar problem before and the reason is that the user "redis" do not have the write authority in the folder of "dump.rdb".bgsave is the default way to backup data to disk in redis. so i run the code " config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no" in redis.cli and the problem be fixed.what's more,you also can change the folder of the "dump.rdb" in redis.conf.

Comment: Thanks, but I don´t think the problem is of writing permissions, because with other smaller  dump.rdb file it runs correctly